# Error EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION in Xcode 8/Swift 3 but not in Xcode 7.3.1/Swift 2

Tags: ios, xcode, swift2, swift3, xcode8

The code below works fine in Swift 2.0 but in Swift 3.0, it give the error:

"error: Execution was interrupted, reason: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)"
Here's a picture of the details ("Show Result") on the playground for Xcode 8/Swift 3:
￼
[Details of error that happens in the Xcode 8 playground - Swift 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uAYh0.png)

I didn't have to make major changes in the Swift 2.0 code to convert it to Swift 3.0, except maybe add "_" before arguments, then it forced me to add as! ((NSError?, URLResponse?, AnyObject?) -> ()) to the callback argument in the request call.

So, the code under "Swift 3.0" below gives an error while the code from the old Swift 2.0 works with no error. I tried both in a playground for their associated versions.

Swift 3.0 (Xcode 8 playground):

```
public func post(url: String, data: [String: String] = [String: String](), auth: [String: String] = [String: String](), callback: ((_ err: NSError?, _ response: HTTPURLResponse?, _ body: AnyObject?)->())? = nil) {
    let qs = "id=123&username=myusername&password=mypwd&"
    request(["url": url, "method" : "POST", "body" : qs, "auth" : auth] , callback: callback as! ((NSError?, URLResponse?, AnyObject?) -> ()))
}

func request(_ options: [String: Any], callback: ((_ err: NSError?, _ response: HTTPURLResponse?, _ body: AnyObject?)->())) {

}


var data = [
    "username" : "my name",
    "password" : "my pass",
    "device_id" : "my uuid"
]


post(url: "my url", data: data, callback: {err, response, body in
     if( err == nil ) {

     }
})
```

Swift 2.0 (Xcode 7.3.1 playground):

```
public func post(url: String, data: [String: String] = [String: String](), auth: [String: String] = [String: String](), callback: ((err: NSError?, response: NSHTTPURLResponse?, body: AnyObject?)->())? = nil) {
    let qs = "id=123&username=myusername&password=mypwd&"
    request(["url": url, "method" : "POST", "body" : qs, "auth" : auth] , callback: callback )
}

func request(options: [String: Any], callback: ((err: NSError?, response: NSHTTPURLResponse?, body: AnyObject?)->())?) {

}


var data = [
    "username" : "my name",
    "password" : "my pass",
    "device_id" : "my uuid"
]


post("my url", data: data, callback: {err, response, body in
    if( err == nil ) {

    }
})
```

Comment: The major difference between the snippets is `callback as!` which is most likely the reason of the crash.

Comment: Thanks for your comment vadian, but it actually forced me to make that change. How do you propose this may be fixed?

Comment: Don't forced unwrap values uncritically, check for `nil`or use optional bindings.

Comment: Thanks. I'll check.

Comment: @Vadian the Swift 3 conversion wizard adds the "as! (Data?, URLResponse?, Error?) -> Void)" itself ....